# Convert large dataset from wide to long format in bash (using awk or similar)

Tags: bash, dataframe, machine-learning, awk

I am preparing a long format dataset for a machine learning workflow. The dataset is in long format in the following csv format:

```
ID,color,number,location
A1,white,6,water
A1,green,4,water
A1,blue,7,water
A2,white,4,land
A2,green,8,land
A2,red,4,land
A3,white,3,land
A3,green,6,land
A3,red,4,land
A4,white,4,water
A4,green,6,water
A4,blue,4,water
```

And my desired output of the wide format data is as follows (note that missing color values for an ID are interpreted as 0):

```
ID,location,white,green,blue,red
A1,water,6,4,7,0
A2,land,4,8,0,4
A3,land,3,6,0,4
A4,water,4,6,4,0
```

I have tried using methods in R (e.g. `widedata <- dcast(longdata, ID + location ~ color, value.var = "number", sum)`) which would have been very easy, but ran into issues with memory as the dataset is somewhat large (~200GB). I would like to use a stream processing approach (e.g. awk) though I am a beginner in this case (I can reorganize columns and perform functions but not sure how to manipulate the structure of the data frame).

Comment: This is an interesting problem.  How many unique IDs (A1, A2, etc.) are there?  Is each ID guaranteed to have only one location?

Comment: Can we assume that **1** the lines are sorted by ID **2** there is only land and water for location **3** there are only the 4 colors?  This will greatly simplify the potential suggestions.  If it must be completly generic, it will be harder.

Comment: If you can split your data set based on the ID (like 1 file per ID), your R method might work on these smaller files.  Try to cut your large dataset into smaller chunks you can process.

Comment: @BillDoughty there are about 137 IDs total repeated many times, though they are sequential like the example above. And yes, each ID is guaranteed to only have one location.

Comment: If the tool needs to determine all possible colors to print in the header line and determine output ordering by reading the input then a "stream approach" that doesn't read everything into memory first is impossible. If you can provide a list of all possible colors on the command line **then** a stream approach is possible. So - do all colors have to be read from  the input or can you provide them as an argument to the tool?

Comment: You say there are 137 unique ids, locations are also unique per ID, colors are only 4. How is this 200GB? Is your output expected to have one row per ID,location, or not?

Comment: I __suspect__ that you want to print many rows for same ID, one per block of sequential appearence of that ID. In such a case, things change. But this is only a guess.

Answer (score 3):

Since you said you `ran into issues with memory as the dataset is somewhat large (~200GB)` - this stores **very** little in memory (just an array of unique colors and then the color values for 1 ID at a time), instead it uses a 2-pass approach to first collect all of the colors and then print the values for each color per ID, and so it'll work no matter how large your input file is (unless you have a massive number of lines for a given ID, of course, e.g. your whole 200GB file only has 1 unique ID with billions of colors):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    if (NR > 1 ) {
        colors[$2]
    }
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    printf "%s%s%s", $1, OFS, $NF
    for (color in colors) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, color
    }
    print ""
    next
}
$1 != prev[1] {
    if ( FNR > 2 ) {
        prt()
    }
    split($0,prev)
}
{ values[$2] = $3 }
END { prt() }

function prt(   color, value) {
    printf "%s%s%s", prev[1], OFS, prev[NF]
    for (color in colors) {
        value = values[color]
        printf "%s%d", OFS, value
    }
    print ""
    delete values
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
ID,location,red,white,blue,green
A1,water,0,6,7,4
A2,land,4,4,0,8
A3,land,4,3,0,6
A4,water,0,4,4,6
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell/OS on every UNIX or Windows box.

The above does not use `a stream processing approach` as you asked for because that's not possible while still addressing your memory usage concern. Since you need to print a list of all possible colors on  the header line you MUST parse the data twice which means you either read it all into memory and then process it from memory once everythings been stored, or you do what the above does and processes it twice from disk without reading it into memory first.

If you can provide a list of all colors as an argument to the tool **then** you can do a stream approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
    numCols = split(colors,cols)
}
FNR == 1 {
    printf "%s%s%s", $1, OFS, $NF
    for (c=1; c<=numCols; c++) {
        color = cols[c]
        printf "%s%s", OFS, color
    }
    print ""
    next
}
$1 != prev[1] {
    if ( FNR > 2 ) {
        prt()
    }
    split($0,prev)
}
{ values[$2] = $3 }
END { prt() }

function prt(   color, value, c) {
    printf "%s%s%s", prev[1], OFS, prev[NF]
    for (c=1; c<=numCols; c++) {
        color = cols[c]
        value = values[color]
        printf "%s%d", OFS, value
    }
    print ""
    delete values
}
```

.

```
$ cat file | awk -v colors='red,white,blue,green' -f tst.awk
ID,location,red,white,blue,green
A1,water,0,6,7,4
A2,land,4,4,0,8
A3,land,4,3,0,6
A4,water,0,4,4,6
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are millions of unique color IDs, but the first block of code worked well on a few thousand rows. I will continue testing/calculating total memory requirements before attempting the full dataset.

Comment: When you say "color IDs" idk if you mean the "color" or "ID" field from your input (`ID,color,...`). In any case, millions of unique colors and/or millions of unique IDs are no problem at all. The only possible memory problem would be if there were billions or trillions (not just millions) of colors and only 1 or 2 IDs which I think is **extremely** unlikely.

Comment: unless of course if the OP is using color/location as "mnemonic stubs" to simplify the task/understanding - whereas in reality some (?) of the columns have different connotation.

Comment: @EdMorton **"The above will work using any awk"**. You probably want to change `delete values` to `split("",values)` to work with ANY awk...

Comment: `delete array` has been part of POSIX for 8+ years now and was included in all of the most commonly used awks before that. If you're running a version of any awk that doesn't support it then it's time to upgrade your awk version. See https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=544 for more info.

Comment: @EdMorton I meant "color". Played around with it and this is working very well with larger samples of the dataset. The only significant change I made was changing the modifier at around line 30 from %d to %g (as many values were decimals). I definitely appreciate the flexibility of this approach.

Answer (score 2):

this is a bit verbose, but should ease the comprehension.
Assuming you have `gawk` and its version is **4.0++**
`gawk -f geo.awk myCsvFile.csv` where **geo.awk** is:

```
BEGIN {
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR>1 {
  a[$1][$4][$2]=$3
  cols[$2]
}
END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
  printf("ID,location")
  for(i in cols)
     printf("%s%s", OFS, i)
  printf ORS
  for(id in a)
    for(loc in a[id]) {
      printf("%s%s%s", id, OFS, loc)
      for (col in cols)
         printf("%s%d", OFS, (col in a[id][loc])? a[id][loc][col]:0)
      printf ORS
    }
}
```

results in:

```
ID,location,blue,green,red,white
A1,water,7,4,0,6
A2,land,0,8,4,4
A3,land,0,6,4,3
A4,water,4,6,0,4
```

Comment: Can confirm this worked on smaller sample sets of the data. I've yet to test it on the entire dataset though.

Comment: Obviously YMMV reading a 200GB file into memory and the OP already said they ran into issues trying to do so with a different tool, R, so it's highly likely they will (if not now then with some other input later) with awk too.